# jQuery if new line, add +1 to line count

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

I am making a javascript code editor online, and right now I'm doing the line count on the left side of the editor. I can't figure out how to make it so when a new line is created, it adds +1 to the line count, so each new line it it will have the line number on the left. Anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.split()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split) to split each occurrence into an array, then get the array count.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().lastIndexOf('\n')!=-1)
        x = $(this).val().split('\n');
    $('div').text(x.length); // This will be the line number
});​
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WkVb9/

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of \n instances in a string, and apply it recursively to the left side div that contains the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check each input, if it is a `\n`, just + 1. Hope to see a better answer...